# Exp:resso Store - Auto-Calculate Shipping Based on Address

Tags: expresso-store

Looking for a bit of help with Exp:resso Store's USPS shipping plugin. Either I'm not looking at the correct page in the documentation, or it just isn't fully documented. Being new to this, it makes no sense to me. Your help is appreciated. :)

I WAS using the native, built in shipping feature that comes with the Store module itself. I had 2 shipping rules in place, but as my husband pointed out, if they only order one, tiny thing, it's unfair to charge the flat rate postage. Indeed.

Thinking it would help, I purchased the USPS shipping plugin. I have it installed, and have my USPS API username in place. I have it set to Variable Container Size, International Mailtype set to ALL, even though I do not ship outside of the U.S, and have "Priority" checked under "Service - US Only". (As a sidenote, regardless of unchecking all of the international options and saving my preferences, I come back only to find them re-checked.)

I implemented this code on my FIRST checkout page:

```
<td>Shipping</td>
<td colspan="2">
<select name="shipping_method">
<option value="">Select a shipping method...</option>
{shipping_methods}
<option value="{method_id}">{method_title} ({method_price})</option>
{/shipping_methods}
</select>


{if error:shipping_method}
<p class="TCBHelpBlock">
{error:shipping_method}</p>
{/if}
</td>
<td style="text-align:right">
{order_shipping}
</td>
```

What I'm aiming for is shipping to be calculated based on the customer's address, which I realize isn't input until the 2nd checkout page; however, what's happening on the first page is one of 2 things: If I already have shipping rules in place in the native shipping feature, it automatically puts the shipping amount next to the dropdown, regardless of whether or not it's selected, or B) if I delete the native shipping rules I created, I'm left with a select field with no options.

I presumed that the USPS Shipping plugin would have automatically placed "Priority Mail" in the dropdown list, but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a fully detailed example code somewhere that I can peek?

Sorry for the length; just trying to give all the details...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

USPS, UPS, and FedEx all require that you at least have the users zip, state and city entered for it to work. As of Store 2 the shipping drop down will only show shipping options eligible for your address (this prevents seeing international shipping rates for example if you live in the US and it is coming from the US. You will need to either move your shipping option selection until after your users enter their shipping information or have the user create an account and save their shipping details before going through the checkout process.

Comment: (I'm having to write my response in 3 part, because this thing is limiting my characters. :( )

Hi, Justin! My apologies for not getting back to you before now. 

I think I understand what you mean; I've moved the shipping feature from checkout 1 to checkout 3, and placed it in the summary that appears before customers hit the "Place Order" button. (See next)

Comment: I disabled my native shipping rules, and now only have the USPS plugin's shipping showing; however, I had to place an "Update Cart" button on the page so that their shipping cost would update. Regardless, they can just hit "Place Order" and get away with not paying shipping. Not good. (See next)

Comment: How do I make it so that the shipping is automatically input (and NOT selectable) upon the page load of checkout 3 (which, of course, appears after they've already entered their shipping address)? 
Also, something else I noticed. There appears to be no way to specify the size of the shipping container. Shipping to, say, Florida, might be 7.05 according to the plugin, but their order quantity may dictate I use a much larger box than the plugin accounts for. How would I go about fixing that?

Again, many thanks for all of your help! It's much appreciated.